# Which ISO image do I use for 64-bit Freescale Power PC?

Tags: installation, iso

I have a desktop with a 64-bit Freescale Power PC.  Do I sue the ISO image for AMD64 processor or the 64-bit image for MAC?

Answer (score 0):

PowerPC is a different architecture than x86 and is not officially supported by Canonical. There is a community supported version which you can find [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/) as `ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso`. I tried it a year or so ago on an old G5 and it seemed to work fine, but I'm not sure what extent of software in the software center has been ported to PowerPC.

When the Playstation3 (which also uses a PowerPC CPU) supported booting Linux, most people went with [Yellow Dog Linux](http://www.yellowdoglinux.com/), which supposedly has better PowerPC support.